# Trying to purposely throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm very, very new to coding and currently taking a class for Java. For our most recent assignment, we have to purposely throw several different Built-in Exceptions, even though to my understanding you don't have to manually do this. I'm currently trying to throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with a try and finally statement.

My code currently looks like this:

```java
public class ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptionThrown {

    static void demo() {
        System.out.println("Asked for index 10");
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid array index!");
    } // end of demo

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numbers = new int[5];
        try {
            System.out.println(numbers[10]);
        } finally {
            demo();
        }
    }// end of main

} // end of ArrayIOOBE
```

And that does seem to work, but Java is **also** giving me two Exception errors on its own. Is this normal? Does Java always automatically show me Exceptions on its own even after I've manually asked it to throw one?

Comment: Well, `numbers[10]` throws an exception, and you also throw one in `demo`. I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: An AIOOBE exception will automatically be thrown if an attempt is made to access an array at an invalid index. You do this with `numbers[10]` (the index `10` is out of bounds for the `numbers` array of length `5`). That's where one exception is coming from. The other exception is coming from the one you throw in `demo()`. And note that `finally` is _always_ executed if the associated `try` has been entered (ignoring special situations, such as a call to `System.exit(...)`). So, even though `numbers[10]` is throwing an exception, the `finally` block is still executed, and thus so is `demo()`.

Comment: Yes, this should throw 2 exceptions, 1 due to accessing numbers[10] (as you are not catching it) and then the one you throw intentionally in finally block. JVM will throw the exception when it occurs (if you haven't catch) regardless of what you have done.

Comment: You should only see one exception reported by the JVM, as an exception thrown in a finally block hides the original exception. But yes, two exceptions are being thrown. Why are you manually throwing the exception? If the goal of the exercise is to cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException the array access is sufficient.

Comment: @tgdavies Our assignment specifically asks us to manually throw the exception, which kind of puzzled me, but I can't argue with what the professor wants

Comment: TY @CodeIntro, your answer was very informative. All of this is so new to me, so that was helpful!

Comment: TY @Slaw! Now I totally understand why it's throwing two, and why!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Though I recommend getting some clarification from your professor. The use of `try`-`finally` here is confusing because, as noted, the exception from `demo()` _should_ be hiding the exception from `numbers[10]` due to `demo()` being called in the `finally` block (throwing an exception or returning a value from `finally` "overrides" any exception or return from the associated `try` or `catch`). Perhaps what your professor wants is for you to create a method that takes an array and an index, which manually checks `index >= 0 && index < array.length`, throwing as appropriate.